JD-GUI and Java 17
is there a way to make JD-GUI work with JARs compiled with Java 17?
It opens the JARs and decompiles the code, but it cannot extract the members of a class (it shows "null" in the left tree) and if you click on the name of a class within the code, it cannot locate the code of the corresponding class and therefore does not open the respective code. For the same reason, search does not work either.

Latest JD-GUI version 1.6.6 was released in 2019 and Java 17 was released in 2021.--

If you are looking for a newer decompiler with GUI try https://github.com/ThexXTURBOXx/Luyten
